# Executing keystrokes programmatically in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Is it possible to simulate a keyboard press event? Such as pressing enter in a Vaadin textfield? Adding a newline char programmatically does not trigger the value change event but user interaction/keystroke does.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to accomplish is submit a value with enter. If so, look at using a [click shortcut](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/create-ui/shortcut/#adding-click-shortcuts)

```java
TextField userName = new TextField("User name");
PasswordField password = new PasswordField("Password");

Button login = new Button("Login");
login.addClickListener(event -> this.login());
login.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);
```

Comment: not quite, I wanted to trigger a keyboard press (like Enter) programmatically instead of a shortcut, this is not for value submission but rather for dynamic formatting